# Adding one day to an input type date value

Tags: jquery

In HTML I have a date input:

```
<input type="date" id="checkInDate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
```

And I subscribe to the change event using jquery:

```
$('#checkInDate').on('change', function()
{
});
```

How do I get the chosen value of that input date, add one to that date and set another input (checkOutDate) to that value? Below is what I currently have:

```
$('#checkInDate').on('change', function()
{
    var checkInDate = $(this).val();
    console.log(checkInDate); // result is yyyy-mm-dd, ex: 2015-02-20
    var split = checkInDate.split('-');
    var tomorrow = new Date(split[0], split[1], split[2], 0,0,0,0);
    console.log(tomorrow); // result is Wed Mar 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600     (Mountain Daylight Time)
});
```

However this is incorrect as the month 02 is being treated as the third month as months are 0-based.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to achieve? Are you wanting to have the date of the day after the one found in `checkInDate`?

Comment: Yes. However when I add a day using getDate()+1 if checkInDate is the last day of the month then the assign will not work, for example if checkInDate is 2015-02-28, I add one but 2015-02-29 is an invalid date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify this using the [valueAsDate](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-valueasdate) attribute:

```js
$('#checkInDate')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();

$('#checkInDate').change(function() {
  var date= this.valueAsDate;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  $('#checkOutDate')[0].valueAsDate = date;
});

$('#checkInDate').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check-in Date:  <input type="date" id="checkInDate" >  <br>
Check-out Date: <input type="date" id="checkOutDate" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, months are 0-based, so you have to fix the month value, and you can set the day one in advance with some subtle changes to your `new Date()` call.

Here's an example:

```js
var checkInDate = "2015-02-13";
var split = checkInDate.split('-');
var tomorrow = new Date(parseInt(split[0]), parseInt(split[1] - 1), parseInt(split[2]) + 1, 0,0,0,0);
alert(tomorrow);
```

Comment: I don't mind down-votes, but an explanation would be preferable to hit and runs, especially when the code above appears to meet what is desired to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `Date` object has a `getDate()` method

```
var dateObj = new Date(split[0], split[1], split[2], 0,0,0,0);
var tomorrow = dateObj.getDate()+1; 
console.log(tomorrow);
```

Comment: This will return the day only

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract `1` in the month as in `JS` months start from `0`

And use `getDate()` and `setDate()` functions

```
var tomorrow = new Date(split[0], split[1]-1, split[2], 0,0,0,0);
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate()+1); 
console.log(tomorrow);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it but it's not correct. getDate return the day only.

Comment: I guess i should not have equate setDate to tomorrow, that was just a typo. Check the updated one. Now its giving perfect results. http://jsfiddle.net/f5btzh4j/

Comment: Not if the user chooses the last day of a month.

Comment: @andrewb why dont you just see my fiddle. Its 31st Jan converting into 1st  Feb.  http://jsfiddle.net/f5btzh4j

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#checkInDate').on('change', function()
{
    var checkInDate = $(this).val();
    var split = checkInDate.split('-');
    var tomorrow = new Date(split[0], split[1]-1, parseInt(split[2])+1, 0,0,0,0);
    $('#checkOutDate')[0].valueAsDate = tomorrow;
});
```

See JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/61bkhok3/1/